# Using arithmetic with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, assignment-operator

> 2. Two quantities u and v are said to be at right angles if
>
>    nuv = u1v1 + u2v2 + u3v3 + u4v4 +………… + unvn = 0
>
> Write a function that computes whether u and v are at right angles. You may use arrays if you wish. The function can assume that the vectors have the same dimension (n, say), but this number should be passed as a parameter to the function.

I have a few errors in my program. I'd appreciate some help, as I'm a beginner. The errors are telling me:

> In function 'void function(int*,int*)'
>   cpp 26: error expected ';' before '}' token
>   cpp 29: error ;value required as left operand of assignment

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

const int n = 5;

void function(int array[n],int array2[n]);

int main(){

    int array[n] = {5, 3 , -4, 2, 8};
    int array2[n] ={-7, -9, 5, 2, 9};

    function(array, array2);

    return 0;
}

void function(int array[n], int array2[n]){

    int multiple;

    for(int i=0; i <=5, i++)
    {
        (array[i]*array2[i]) + (array[i+1]*array2[i+1]) = multiple;
    }

    cout << multiple << endl;
}
```

Comment: initialize multiple to zero; then multiple += (..)

Comment: Don't call your function `function`. Call it a meaningful name, like `DotProduct`.

Comment: `i <=5` you are accessing the array out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error is where you are using the `for` loop in this fashion:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5,i++)
```

Use this instead:

```
for(int i=0; i <= 5; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks I've just corrected this I still have issues with the void function (int* int*) and 29 lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob: that is because your assignment of `multiple` is backwards

Comment: Yes that is the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is malformed.  You need to use `<` instead of `<=`, use `n` instead of `5`, and use `;` instead of `,`.

Your assignment of `multiple` is backwards.  The value on the right-side of the `=` operator is assigned to the variable on the left-side of `=`.  You are trying to assign the value of `multiple` (which is uninitialized) to a dynamically computed value that has no explicit variable of its own.  You should be assigning the computed value to `multiple` instead.

Also, you didn't follow the "this number [array dimensions] should be passed as a parameter to the function" requirement of your instructions.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std; 

const int n = 5;

void function(const int *array1, const int *array2, const int size);

int main()
{
    int array1[n] = { 5,  3, -4, 2, 8};
    int array2[n] = {-7, -9,  5, 2, 9};

    function(array1, array2, n);

    return 0;
}

void function(const int *array1, const int *array2, const int size)
{
    int multiple = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        multiple += (array1[i] * array2[i]);
    }

    cout << multiple << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The function can assume that the vectors have the same dimension (n,
>   say), **but this number should be passed as a parameter to the
>   function**.

This function declaration

```
void function(int array[n],int array2[n]);
```

does not include a parameter that specifies the dimension of the arrays.

The above declaration is equivalent to

```
void function(int *array,int *array2);
```

because arrays passed by value are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

There are a typo and a bug in this for statement

```
for(int i=0; i <=5, i++)
             ^^^^^^
```

There shall be

```
for ( int i=0; i < n; i++)
```

The variable `multiple`

```
int multiple;
```

is not initialized and this assignment

```
(array[i]*array2[i]) + (array[i+1]*array2[i+1]) = multiple;
```

does not have sense and has nothing common with the condition

```
nuv = u1v1 + u2v2 + u3v3 + u4v4 +………… + unvn = 0
```

It seems what you mean is the following

```
#include <iostream>

bool function( const int array[], const int array2[], size_t n ) 
{

    long long int product = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        product += array[i] * array2[i];
    }

    return product == 0;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int array[N]  = { 5, 3 , -4, 2, 8 };
    int array2[N] = { -7, -9, 5, 2, 9 };

    std::cout << "array and array2 are "
        << (function(array, array2, N) ? "" : "not ")
        << "at right angles"
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

These arrays

```
    int array[N]  = { 5, 3 , -4, 2, 8 };
    int array2[N] = { -7, -9, 5, 2, 9 };
```

are not a right angles,

But these arrays

```
    int array[N]  = { 5, 3 , -4, 1, 9 };
    int array2[N] = { -7, -9, 5, 1, 9 };
```

are at right angles. Try them.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: try the C++ way. Use std::array that knows it's length. Use algorithms provided by the standard library like std::inner_product.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
  using arr_t = std::array<int,5>;

  arr_t arr1 = {5, 3 , -4, 2, 8};
  arr_t arr2 = {-7, -9, 5, 2, 9};

  int mult = std::inner_product( begin(arr1), end(arr1), begin(arr2), 0,
                 std::plus<>(), std::multiplies<>() );

  std::cerr << mult << "\n";
}
```